# VS 2019 - core 5.0 - Error adding WCF Web Service reference

Tags: web-services, visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to add a reference to web service in VS 2019.
I think the installation might be damaged?
After I right click on the Connected Services node in the Solution Explorer and choose Add Connected Service... then I pick Microsoft WCF Service Reference Provider...
Then I paste my URI for the wsdl into the URL input field.. and click go..
The following is displayed...

```
Resolving project references ...
Importing web service metadata ...
Number of service endpoints found: 1
Scaffolding service reference code ...
Error:Unable to find deps.json generator project.
```

Am I right in thinking this deps.json is something that is missing in the install and would necessitate a repair ??
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yep, checked this against another installation of visual studio and there was a missing folder.
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.203\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\GenerateDeps

So, copied that folder and contents over and all ok...